# Saving data in table in SQL Server 2005

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

I am asp.net developer and I work with SQL Server 2005 .

I have a table with 4 columns

say

1. Name
2. RollNo
3. Std
4. Div

if client enters

1. Name
2. RollNo
3. Std

but doesn't enters 4.Div column data and try's to save data, it should not give error, it should save the data in database

Comment: is the Div column non-nullable?

Comment: if yes what will be the problem ? and if not then what will be the problem ? can u kindly explain ??

Comment: @user404305, if you have the column set for non-nullable it will be expecting a value, if you don't provide one, your user will get an error screen and the insert won't go through. If the column allows nulls then the insert will go through fine with no data for the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI,

That means that you need to save with either default division for standard or null value.

You can setup in database to allow null and do not pass anything and that saves the data with null values.

Otherwise, I think you should put default value in Div for that standard. So whenever you dont pass that value in Insert statement, it takes default one.

Will it help or do I misunderstood it?

Answer (score 1):

So it is giving you an error? Make sure that you set 4. Div column to "Allow Nulls"(No value).
It's also good to know that SQL Server can be set up to insert a default value if one isn't provided.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you're going to have NULL in one of your fields (provided you allow nulls in the fields). Depending on where you're experiencing your problem, your code would need to test for NULL from the information a client inputs or your code will need to test for NULL when it retrieves the information.

If you're running into an error, it might be prudent to post details of the error as well.